# (Odoo) Show image from a url without storing it in the database

Tags: odoo

I have a URL of a saved image on Amazon stored in a char field, I want to show that URL as an Image field without storing it in the Odoo database. What is the best way to do this? I am asking because I bought a module from the Odoo App store that allows me to edit images stored in an image field (fields.Image()).

Thanks